# google apps script jbdc sql server database connection string error

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, connection-string, server-error

I'm trying to connect to my local sql server database at my home network using the code that I found from this site [Querying SQL Server with Google Apps Script via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440939/querying-sql-server-with-google-apps-script-via-jdbc) about 3 years ago which was marked being correct. However, I get the error message **"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."**. This error is from line 2 where the connection string is defined. I retried several times, but I always get the same error. When I searched this error, it seems like it could be too many things and I was not able to find any answers for my issue. Thanks.

This was the code that was marked being correct:

```
function readAzure() {
     var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://XYZ.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=MYDATABSENAME","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
     var stmt = conn.createStatement();
     var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from helloworld");

     var doc = SpreadsheetApp.create('azure');
     var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
     var row = 0;
     while(rs.next()) {
     cell.offset(row, 0).setValue(rs.getString(1));
     cell.offset(row, 1).setValue(rs.getString(2));
     row++;
     }


   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
       conn.close();

}
```

I also found another connection string code and when I try this format I get the same error.

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IP-address:1433;" + "databaseName=DBName;user=username;password=password;");
```

Comment: Is your server available? Try to connect from another client. I'd like [Valentina Studio](http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview) May be your server uses an additional encryption?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#setup_for_other_databases), you need to ensure that your database accepts connections from any of Apps Script's IP addresses. These are the address ranges you'll need to whitelist.

```
64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255
66.249.80.0 - 66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255
74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
173.194.0.0 - 173.194.255.255
207.126.144.0 - 207.126.159.255
209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255
```

Also, from the documentation link above, there is a sample code that you can follow to set up external database via JDBC.

Here is a code that demonstrates how to write a single record to the database as well as a batch of 500 records.

```
// Replace the variables in this block with real values.
var address = 'database_IP_address';
var user = 'user_name';
var userPwd = 'user_password';
var db = 'database_name';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;

// Write one row of data to a table.
function writeOneRecord() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO entries '
      + '(guestName, content) values (?, ?)');
  stmt.setString(1, 'First Guest');
  stmt.setString(2, 'Hello, world');
  stmt.execute();
}

// Write 500 rows of data to a table in a single batch.
function writeManyRecords() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO entries '
      + '(guestName, content) values (?, ?)');
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    stmt.setString(1, 'Name ' + i);
    stmt.setString(2, 'Hello, world ' + i);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }

  var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
  conn.commit();
  conn.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms for %s rows.', end - start, batch.length);
}
```

For more information, just read through to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) and check this [thread](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JDBCAndMySQL) and related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049966/connecting-google-spreadsheets-to-mysql-w-jdbc).

Comment: The whitelist that is published in the Google apps script dev page worked when I did tried the code on cloud sql server database. I had not had a chance to try your code, but basically in addition to the syntax, the traffic route configuration would be required which I was able to do on my cloud network. thanks.