# Execute SQL server 2008 stored procedure from google script

Tags: sql-server

I'm just wondering if you can execute a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure using google script? If so, how to do it? Thanks guys

Comment: I very much doubt it, unless your SQL server is open to the internet, so that Google's servers can see it. But that would be generally considered a security risk and is rarely done. Maybe if your database was in azure it might be accessible, or you take some unusual steps to open up access to an on premises database. But in theory you can do it. Did you search for anything about this before asking? Because it's not hard to find information...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying SQL Server with Google Apps Script via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440939/querying-sql-server-with-google-apps-script-via-jdbc)

Comment: I'd be wary of having a SQL Server 2008 instance open to the outside world too. It has less than 2 months of support left so if it's open after that and then a security flaw found, it won't be patched and will be open for exploit.

Comment: allright, thanks guys, this has been very informative

Comment: If you're talking about Google Apps Script then yes.  :)  
Just send it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The basic bit to call the procedure is done using "CALL"

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

var selectquery = '{CALL ThisIsNameOfTheStoredProcedure}';
var stmt = conn.prepareCall(selectquery);
var results = stmt.executeQuery();
if (results.next()) {....do stuff ....}
```